# TypeScript: How to specify the type of an object's value, if the ':' character is already reserved?

Tags: typescript

I have an object with a key `item` whose value type could be `undefined | Box`. I have to initiate it as `undefined`, and at a later time I'll substitute that value with a `Box`.

```ts
const myObjs = {
    "obj1" : {x: 0, y: 1, z: 3, item: undefined},
    "obj2" : {x: 0, y: 1, z: 3, item: undefined}
};
```

This gives me the error

> Object literal's property 'item' implicitly has an 'any' type.

So I created a custom type, but I cannot use it because the symbol `:` is already in use in an object:

```ts
type boxType = undefined | Mesh;

const myObjs = {
    "obj1" : {x: 0, y: 1, z: 3, item: boxType: undefined},
    "obj2" : {x: 0, y: 1, z: 3, item: boxType: undefined}
};
```

How do I tell my object that `item` should be of type `boxType`?

Comment: Why not just create a type for `myObj`?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Sorry, I edited my question to show that the object is also a value inside another object.

Comment: Then, another question: what is the purpose of having `item` initialized as `undefined` instead of just being absent? I know there are edge cases in which it is desirable to have the property present as `undefined`, but are you operating one of those edge cases?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen It will improve DX autocompletion imo and help from setting wrong property name later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly suggest just typing everything:

```
type Mesh = any;

type ObjectType = {
  x: number;
  y: number;
  z: number;
  item?: Mesh; // Mesh or undefined
}

const myObjs: {[key: string]: ObjectType} = {
    "obj1" : {x: 0, y: 1, z: 3},
    "obj2" : {x: 0, y: 1, z: 3, item: undefined} // if you *really* need this
};
```

Comment: Excellent, I thought I was going to have to use `... as ObjectType` at the end of each entry. This is a much more elegant solution. And you're right, making `item` optional makes it unnecessary to declare as `undefined`, since I could just as well check for its existence.

Comment: You could also simplify `{[key: string]: ObjectType}` with `Record<string, ObjectType>`, where `Record` is a native TS type that defines an object with key and value type generics.

Answer (score 1):

This should be

```ts
const myObj = {x: 0, y: 1, z: 3, item: undefined as boxType };
```

Answer (score 1):

Either list out all the properties together

```
const myObj: {
  x: number;
  y: number;
  z: number;
  item: undefined | Mesh;
} = { x: 0, y: 1, z: 3, item: undefined };
```

or, more concisely but requiring an ugly type assertion, use `as` after the item.

```
const myObj = {x: 0, y: 1, z: 3, item: undefined as undefined | Mesh };
```